# CSV different row count on windows and linux

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading a csv from a gzip file. that file has ~700.000 lines and works fine on windows. on linux however, the file appears to have 2.2 million lines.

```
with gz.open(path, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as csv_file:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
   print(len(list(csv_reader)))
```

Output windows: 730711

Output linux: 2200364

How do I get the correct output on linux?

Comment: Not sure there's a way to know what's going on without access to your data file. Maybe you can try [`csv.Sniffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer) to deduce the exact format/dialect of the file so that it can be read consistently on any platform.

Comment: `gunzip` the file first, then count the true number of newlines with `wc -l` and let us know

Comment: @Woodford its one of the csv's from the twitch earnings leak, using the dialect from sniffer didnt help sadly

Comment: @WalterTross doing wc -l on the file on linux results in the same number as on windows 730711

Comment: oh, that's weird. I thought you had a combination of `\r\n` and `\n`, but then you would see the higher number with `wc -l`. Is there a public link to your input file?

Comment: i dont know if i'm allowed to link it since its technically leaked, but if you google "twitch leak magnet link" there is a result for the computerbase.de forum which has the magnet link. I am using the very first file in ../all_revenues/2019/08/28/all_revenues.csv.gz @WalterTross

Comment: sorry, I can't help you, my company's computer (the only one I have) won't let me see that :-(

Comment: you could try `head -1 unzippedfile | od -tx1` to see the bytes of the first line. Does it end with `0d 0a` or `0a` only? In a larger dump, are you able to find any `0d` _not_ followed by `0a`? Are text fields never/always/sometimes quoted?

Comment: these are the outputs for the first command: https://i.imgur.com/jloUR03.png, in a larger dump i could not find a single `0d` at all. @WalterTross

Comment: @WalterTross I am reporting back to you right now, because it seems that I have identified the issue. It is a stupid thing on my part, but the snippet i posted is from inside an os.walk() over the file tree of the leak. now after some more research it seems that os.walk iterates through the file tree in a different order on linux, so that a different csv file was used at the first point of the file tree iteration. That all of them have the same name didn't really help it either. but just know that everything works as intended, and I am very thankful for the energy you invested into this

Comment: oh boy... Thanks for stopping me :-D